# JavaScript adding user input to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I recently started learning JavaScript and got stuck. I need to get cars info as an object to cars array. I have three different input's which have to be placed in to array as user types something and presses the button.

here is my code so far:

```
var inpCarName = document.getElementById("carName");
var inpSpeed = document.getElementById("speed");
var inpTime = document.getElementById("time");
var btnCarName = document.getElementById("btnCarName");
var btnRace = document.getElementById("btnRace");

carArray = [];

btnCarName.onclick = function()
{

}
```

Comment: You have every thing. Just push ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the attributes listed above and create a new [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). Then push the various objects into a carArray:

```
carObject = {'inpCarName': inpCarName, 'inpSpeed': inpSpeed, 'inpTime': inpTime, 'btnCarName':btnCarName,'btnRace': btnRace  }
```

Use the [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function to push the new object into the carArray: `carArray.push(carObject)`

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like that:

```
var car = {name:inpCarName, speed:inpSpeed, time:inpTime}; // create the     object
carArray.push(car); //here we insert the object in the array
```

What do you think?

Comment: Also if you want a great foundation to start these videos are fantastic:

https://www.youtube.com/user/techSithTube/videos

Answer (score 0):

Try below:
You need to push the value of the DOM element like `inpCarName.value` where `inpCarName` is a DOM element.

```
var inpCarName = document.getElementById("carName");
var inpSpeed = document.getElementById("speed");
var inpTime = document.getElementById("time");
var btnCarName = document.getElementById("btnCarName");
var btnRace = document.getElementById("btnRace");

carArray = [];

btnCarName.onclick = function(){
carArray.push({name:inpCarName.value, speed:inpSpeed.value, time:inpTime.value});
}
```

Comment: really like this one , seems really simple and it certainly took me less time to understand :D thanks , mate :)

Comment: your code , I suppose, should work just fine , but it just throws an error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null at script.js:9().  And js9 line is : btnCarName.onclick = function()

Comment: That means `document.getElementById("btnCarName");` is returning null which in turn means there is no element with id `btnCarName`

Comment: but it's just nonsens , cause I have button in html with id = "btnCarName". It must be something else...

Answer (score 0):

```
var carinfo ={};
var carArray=[];

carArray.push("Carname":inpCarName,"Speed":inpSpeed,"Time":inpTime);

carinfo={carArray}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.